# Insert data from a populated data table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I need your help to assist me on this problem. So as you can see in Form1.php, I've select data from db which are (flock id, house, breed) and these data will populate the row for the table. The problem is, this form will consist of 2 tables in database.

*flock id, house, breed* -> table1

*age, prev day stock, cull, mortality* -> table2

I want to insert all the data in table2. How do i link the data from table 1 & 2 and save the records in table2?

The below code is the form which i've coding so far. Glad if you can help me.

**Form1.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<?php
include 'db/dbconn.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM flockjawi";
$result = $dbconn->query($sql);
?>
<tr>
  <th>FLOCK ID</th>
  <th>HOUSE</th>
  <th>BREED</th>
  <th>AGE</th>
  <th>PREV DAY STOCK</th>
  <th>CULL</th>
  <th>MORTALITY</th>
</tr>

<?php
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $rows['flockps_id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows['house_code']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows['breed_doc']; ?></td>
  <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
  <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
  <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
  <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</tr>
<?php
  }
 }
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks as if you are accurately echoing the data from the database, correct?   If not, you'll need to start there, make sure you have that right.    You are asking a question where the answer will need to be broken into parts.

Then, modify your HTML form, to echo the data into the inputs.   Name the inputs, and then create some post variables, sanitize them (I recommend PDO bound parameters), and then write a new query  to insert those variables into the database into your new table.

Answer (score 0):

You must add related id column for connecting this tables. In your second table add column named, for example, `flockjawi_id`. While you will add new row, add to this column id from your first table - `flockjawi`.

And then you will have a second table, which will contain rows with related column to the first table.

Comment: I've alreay add the flockjawi_id to the second table. But the most confussing me is how to construct the sql to select and insert both data in second table.

Comment: In the simple case you can just
1. **For add**: `INSERT INTO second_table SET ..., flockjawi_id = 1, ...`
2. **For select**: `SELECT * FROM flockjawi where flockjawi_id = 1`

I mean first you must add row in the flockjawi and get added id. And only then add row to the second table using id from added `flockjawi` row